# filtering table by choosing in combobox

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get the list of diagnosed disease of the patient by choosing his name in the combo box, how can I do that? This is my code.

```
<select name="pname" class="textfields" id="model" style="width:180px;" onchange="getVal1();">
    <option id="0" >--Select Patient Name--</option>

    <?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbnpatient");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $pnum = $_GET['pnum'];
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tblnpatient");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $pnum = $row['pnum'];
        $pname = $row['pname'];
        $addr = $row['addr'];
        $complaints = $row['complaints'];

    ?>

    <option id="<?php echo $pnum; ?>" data-pnum="<?php echo $pnum; ?>" data-addr="<?php echo $addr; ?>" data-complaints="<?php echo $complaints; ?>" value="<?php echo $pname; ?>"><?php echo     $pname; ?></option>

    <?php } ?>
```

This is my code for filtering the table: And i having a trouble in this code because nothings appear in the table when i select the pname

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbnpatient");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$pname = $_GET['pname'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbldiagnosis WHERE pname='$pname'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<tr class="record">';
    echo '<td>'.$row['diagnosis'].'</td>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using ajax.  On change of the select, you can trigger a jQuery call to submit the selected value of the box to your PHP page, which has the MySQL to filter the table.  The returned result will then be displayed on the page in the designated area.

Main Page:

```
<select name="pname">
    <option value="pname-value">pname-value</option>
</select><br>
<div id="query_results"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select[name="pname"]).on('change',function() {
            var curPname=$(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'urltotable.php?pname='+curPname,
                success:function(data) {
                    $("div#query_results").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is a simplified ajax call that will grab the value from the select box named "pname" and it will send that value to the "url" variable in the ajax call via "GET".  This page can then take that variable via GET and use it to get the query results.  Upon successful completion, it will display the results inside the div we added with the ID of "query_results".

You can easily customize the select to use your current PHP as listed above, also.

Now for the "urltotable.php" as we specified above, you can use the table query you have above, but just be sure to add the GET line to it so that your pname variable is accessible to the script:

```
$pname=$_GET["pname"];
```

For more information about Ajax for full features list, [click here to read about Ajax in the jQuery documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)